# Interactive chart, changing the chart after selecting from the list in plotly.express

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I'm trying to make an interactive summary about premier league clubs. I look at goals conceded and goals scored by catch. I would like to add a drop-down list so that the user can choose the club he is interested in. I found such a solution, but it creates more charts for me instead of replacing the original one. Can someone help me with this last step?

```py
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import interact
import plotly.express as px

club_name = 4 * ['Arsenal'] + 4 * ['Liverpool']
type = 2 * ['scored', 'scored', 'lost', 'lost']
half = 2 * ['first', 'second', 'first', 'second']
how_much = 2 * [10, 15, 10, 5]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=zip(club_name, type, half, how_much),
    columns=['club_name', 'type', 'half', 'how_much']
)

def make_chart(team):
    fig = px.bar(
        df[df['club_name'] == team],
        x='type', 
        y='how_much', 
        color='half', 
        barmode='group'
    )
    fig.show()

team_dropdown = interact(make_chart, team=df.club_name.unique())
```

Comment: It seems to me that your post's title does not present the essence of the problem. It is basically about creating an interactive chart with plotly. It does not really matter whether the chart presents the data about Premier League clubs or say varieties of fruit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a nice looking app, i would use ipyvuetify for the UI elements. Also, I tend not to use interact and instead I use the observe statements in ipywidgets.  Also, I find it better to build apps using a class structure.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import ipyvuetify as v

club_name = 4 * ['Arsenal'] + 4 * ['Liverpool']
type = 2 * ['scored', 'scored', 'lost', 'lost']
half = 2 * ['first', 'second', 'first', 'second']
how_much = [10, 15, 10, 5] + [15, 10, 8, 4]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=zip(club_name, type, half, how_much),
    columns=['club_name', 'type', 'half', 'how_much']
)

class Clubapp:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self.select_club = v.Select(v_model =list(df.club_name.unique())[0],  items=list(df.club_name.unique()))
        self.select_club.observe(self.make_chart)
        fig = px.bar(
            self.df[self.df['club_name'] == self.select_club.v_model],
            x='type', 
            y='how_much', 
            color='half', 
            barmode='group'
        )        
        self.figwidget = go.FigureWidget(fig)

        self.card = v.Card(children=[self.select_club,self.figwidget])
        
    def make_chart(self, change):
        fig = px.bar(
            self.df[self.df['club_name'] == self.select_club.v_model],
            x='type', 
            y='how_much', 
            color='half', 
            barmode='group'
        )
        
        # Instead of redisplaying a brand new plot, for smoothness it is better to modify existing graph
        # Swap the y values in the new figure for the existing figure.
        # Could just modify the y values from the dataframe. That might be better
        for num,trace in enumerate(self.figwidget.data):
            trace.y = fig.data[num].y
#         self.card.children= [self.select_club, go.FigureWidget(fig)]

App = Clubapp(df)
App.card
```

[image]